# Java program to connect azure database in Netbeans I'm getting error

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, azure-database-mysql

I'm getting the following error:

I tried various ways I'm getting an error please see the following error.

> run: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.sqldbsamples.App.main(App.java:23)
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

This is my code: please help me with how to connect my database to azure using java program !!!

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Connect to database
        String hostName = "testchinnaa.database.windows.net:1433"; // update me
        String dbName = "Test_Gopi"; // update me
        String user = "chinna"; // update me
        String password = "******"; // update me

        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://testchinnaa.database.windows.net:1433;database=Test_Gopi;user=chinna@testchinna;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
            + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;", hostName, dbName, user, password);
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String schema = connection.getSchema();
            System.out.println("Successful connection - Schema: " + schema);

            System.out.println("Query data example:");
            System.out.println("=========================================");

            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            String selectSql = "SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName "
                + "FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc "  
                + "JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid";

            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql)) {

                // Print results from select statement
                System.out.println("Top 20 categories:");
                while (resultSet.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " "
                        + resultSet.getString(2));
                }
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it mysql or mssql?

Comment: It is mysql using java

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you have to figure out if you are using **MySql** or **MSSql**. You said that you used mysql. However, in your connection string, it is a **sqlserver** which means it is a MSSql.

Here is the tutorial for accessing database using java:

1. You need to download connector for your database:

   - For MySql: [MySQL
     Connector/J](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)
   - For MSSql: [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL
     Server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc)
2. Manually add connector jar file to your classpath. Or you can use Maven dependencies manager to install and configure the Connector/J library in your project.

   ```
   <!-- Example for mysql -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.18</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Code sample

   - For MSSql:

     ```
     try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("conntection_string");
         String SQL = "SELECT name FROM sysdatabases;";

         try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
              ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL)) {

             // Print results from select statement
             while (resultSet.next()) {
                 System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
             }
             connection.close();
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     ```
   - For MySql:

     ```
     Connection conn = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
         String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{server_name}.mysql.database.azure.com:3306?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";;
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "username_from_portal, like: jack@mysqldemo258", "password");
         rs = conn.prepareStatement("show databases").executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){
             System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
         }
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         try{
             if(rs != null) rs.close();
             if(conn != null) conn.close();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: I'm getting this error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to validate the server name in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization. The server name is *.database.windows.net, the name in certificate is cr2.eastus1-a.control.database.windows.net.".
 at

Comment: @chinna98 Which jdbc driver version do you use?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with old version driver. [#623](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/623), [#816](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/816), [#836](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/816).  SO, please check your jdk version and choose right latest driver version.

Comment: @chinna98 Do you have any other problems?

Comment: No..still I didn't check that driver I will check soon